# Async storage returning null value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I am saving a value in async storage react native. But when I try to get the value it returns null. Below is my code . Any help would be appreciated. Value printed in console is fine but async storage returns null.

```
 var userID = responseJson[0].UserId;
 console.log("User id"+userID +userID.toString())
 AsyncStorage.setItem("UserId",userID.toString());              
 AsyncStorage.getItem("UserId", (UserId) => {
   console.log("get user details"+UserId )
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand it's Async method so you won't get it right after you save it. 
You have to get it in callback function. See snippet below:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('UID123', JSON.stringify(UID123_object), () => {
  AsyncStorage.mergeItem('UID123', JSON.stringify(UID123_delta), () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('UID123', (err, result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  });
});
```

[Snippet source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

In your example it will be like:

```
 var userID = responseJson[0].UserId;
            console.log("User id"+userID +userID.toString())
            AsyncStorage.setItem("UserId",userID.toString(), () => {
               AsyncStorage.getItem("UserId", (UserId) => {
                    console.log("get user details"+UserId )}
            });
```

Comment: if i try to get from some other screen then also it returns null

Comment: Have you tried this `try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}` to checked whether you're storing it properly or there's an error ?

Answer (score 0):

The data in the Asyncstorage should be stored in string format. You can do that as:

```
var userID = responseJson[0].UserId;
        console.log("User id"+userID +userID.toString())
        AsyncStorage.setItem("UserId",JSON.stringify(userID));              
        AsyncStorage.getItem("UserId", (err, result) => {
          console.log("get user details"+ result)}
```

Note that the result(data) will be in string format only(irrespective of whether its a variable or an object). In order to use it as object, you need to parse it as object.
You can do that using **JSON.parse(result)**.